# Why is the statusText of my XHR empty?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

When I perform an XHR on our production system, the `statusText` in the response will be an empty string. However, on our development system, the `statusText` will reflect the status correctly.

According to the documentation for [`XMLHttpRequest.statusText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText), it should only be empty while the request is being processed. However, I am seeing this behavior in the `onload` handler.

Additionally, this behavior can only be observed in Chrome and Edge. Firefox will display the correct text.

So, how is the content of the `statusText` actually determined?

Comment: Maybe your production server is running HTTP/2?

Comment: @JulianReschke We're running behind an AWS load balancer (ALB) and, yes, it seems like communication is happening over HTTP/2. What is the connection here?

Comment: There are no reason phrases in HTTP/2.

Comment: @JulianReschke Oh, well that explains it then. If you would put that into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It might be because one server uses HTTP/2, while the other does not. HTTP/2 doesn't have reason phrases anymore.

Comment: After further investigation, this doesn't seem to be correct. It actually seems to be a Chrome-specific issue, possibly related to their implementation of HTTP/2 extensions.

Comment: Well, HTTP/2 does not have reason phrases. Period. It's possible that some UAs *emulate* reason phrases in this case, though.

(see <https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.4.p.2>)

Comment: I have this issue in Chrome but Postman doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at spec:

> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase
> that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.

[rfc7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)

Answer (score 0):

Did your production system use HTTPS and your dev system HTTP by any chance?

For some reason on Chrome `statusText`s started to return empty as soon as we installed an SSL certificate in our server and url requests started with HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Hence, we made sure to use `status` rather than `statusText`.