# With HTTP/2 only, XMLHttpRequest responses' `statusText` property seems to be user-agent defined

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest, http-status-codes, http2

We're sending XHR requests to our backend, thus receiving such kind of response objects (whatever the browser):

```js
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  config: {...},
  data: {...}
}
```

We just migrated to another load balancer that supports HTTP/2. For some reason, the `statusText` property now differs depending on the browser:

**Chrome (56.0.2924.87):**

```js
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: "", // empty
  config: {...},
  data: {...}
}
```

**Firefox (51.0.1):**

```js
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK", // as previously (+1)
  config: {...},
  data: {...}
}
```

**Safari (10.0.3):**

```js
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: "HTTP/2.0 200", // ?!
  config: {...},
  data: {...}
}
```

We had legacy code that was reading that `statusText` property, so some behaviors were broken. It was easily fixed (so it's quite a good point finally), but still, the *why* remains... Any idea what's happening?

Side notes:

- We're using AngularJS 1.x, but [it is simply copying this `statusText` property from the XHR response](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.2/src/ng/http.js#L1051), so this must not be an Angular issue.
- As it seems to depend on the browser, it should not be a load balancer issue... Am I wrong? (DevOps brains needed)
- I was then expecting to find in some specs something like "*`statusText` is user-agent defined, so you should not rely on it*" ([just like Storage#key(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) for example), but neither [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText) nor the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-status-message) provides details about this property.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText)**:

> The XMLHttpRequest.statusText property returns a DOMString containing
>   the response's status message as returned by the HTTP server.

So, it is likely that your load balanced server configuration is not 100% in sync. There could be some server configuration that sends back a different response based on the user-agent making the request.

Comment: Interesting, I personally understood this sentence as "*the server returns a status (e.g. 200, 403), and `statusText` holds the corresponding status message*". In other words, "*the server is in charge of the status only*" so *something* is in charge of filling that property, but I may have misunderstood. And also, if it was backend side, then this should have occurred over HTTP/1.x as well IMHO, what do you think?

Comment: That's not how I interpret it. In fact, it wouldn't make sense for anything but the server to send both the `status` and the `statusText` since future changes to HTTP could result in new responses. This is exactly why I believe that your switch to HTTP/2 in a new load balanced environment is the culprit. I don't think the clients are involved at all (beyond sending their user-agent string to the server).

Comment: Many thanks for your thoughts, I'll double-check these load balancer specs then, I'll keep you informed :)

Comment: Finally, HTTP/2 simply doesn't have this property anymore, @JulianReschke pointed the right link in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41637669/1225328) I hadn't noticed before: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.4.p.2

Comment: Ah, well there you have it!  Thanks for posting the links.